# Can not load powershell module: networkloadbalancingclusters

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, nlb

I get error message during import power-shell module NetworkLoadBalancingClusters on a Win server 2012 R2. The error message is:[image]

I had NLB feature installed. Did I miss something?

[image]

Thanks

Lu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install the administrator tools for NLB?

`Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-NLB`

Comment: Thank U! Manfred :) But may I know why the module didn't be installed during install NLB feature?

Comment: Server components are kept to a strict minimum. Most powershell cmdlets come with the RSAT tools.